# Can I define a grpc call with a null request or response?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Does the rpc syntax in proto3 allow null requests or responses?

e.g. I want the equivalent of the following:

```
rpc Logout;
rpc Status returns (Status);
rpc Log (LogData);
```

Or should I just create a null type?

```
message Null {};

rpc Logout (Null) returns (Null);
rpc Status (Null) returns (Status);
rpc Log (LogData) returns (Null);
```

Answer (score 324, accepted):

Kenton's comment below is sound advice:

> ... we as developers are really bad at guessing what we might want in the future. So I recommend being safe by always defining custom params and results types for every method, even if they are empty.

---

Answering my own question:

Looking through the default proto files, I came across [Empty](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/empty.proto) that is exactly like the Null type I suggested above :)

excerpt from that file:

```
// A generic empty message that you can re-use to avoid defining duplicated
// empty messages in your APIs. A typical example is to use it as the request
// or the response type of an API method. For instance:
//
//     service Foo {
//       rpc Bar(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty);
//     }
//

message Empty {

}
```

Comment: Yes. Empty is the canonical "I don't care" request or response.

I will note, if you think you _may_ want arguments or return values in the future, make a new message that simply has no fields. That way you can add new fields when you need to and not break any application code. Empty is great for when you will never want arguments or return values.

Comment: @EricAnderson is mostly right, but I would argue that we as developers are _really bad_ at guessing what we might want in the future. So I recommend being safe by always defining custom params and results types for every method, even if they are empty.

Comment: "... we as developers are really bad at guessing what we might want in the future.", This would require a seperate `Empty` message for each individual function call? That's quite a sacrifice.

Comment: Does `returns (google.protobuf.Empty);` make the call non-blocking?

Comment: The GRPC wire format supports replacing Empty with a message that has fields in a backwards compatible way, so you don't need a new empty message type for that reason. Having a separate message makes it easier on source code level. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993815/is-google-protobuf-empty-dangerous-for-backwards-compatibility

Comment: @PaulWilliams Have you found an answer to your question?

Comment: @user2233706 it does not make the call non-blocking. You can use an Async Stub to make non-blocking calls. The Blocking Stub still waits for the onCompleted() or onError().

Answer (score 148):

You also can use predefined:

```
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
package MyPackage;

service MyService {
  rpc Check(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}
```