# Is google.protobuf.Empty dangerous for backwards compatibility?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

The [spec](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#empty) for `google.protobuf.Empty` states:

> A generic empty message that you can re-use to avoid defining duplicated
>    empty messages in your APIs. A typical example is to use it as the request
>    or the response type of an API method.

I've been advocating internally to use an empty message wrapper instead, to preserve backwards compatibility. For instance, let's say we have a `FooService`:

```
service Foo {
    rpc List(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (ListResponse) {}
}

message ListResponse {
    repeated Foo results = 1;
}

message Foo {...}
```

If in the future we need to add paging to this list request, we'd need to introduce a request wrapper:

```
message ListRequest {
    int limit = 1;
    int offset = 2;
}
```

and then update the rpc signature:

```
rpc List(ListRequest) returns (ListResponse) {}
```

Is this a backwards-incompatible change, or can the protobuf format handle this gracefully?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The wire format handles this gracefully. However, most code using the gRPC stubs will break as type-safe languages will notice the incompatible types.

If you think you may *ever* need fields, go ahead and make a special message for that case, even if it is empty. If in doubt, do it. If you are confident you will *never* need any fields (the response message of "delete" is a common example), then using `Empty` is fine.

I mentioned this specific case in my [Modifying gRPC Services Over Time](https://kccncna17.sched.com/event/CU7e/modifying-grpc-services-over-time-i-eric-anderson-google) talk. Slides and video recording are available.

Comment: So it's a source code compatibility problem only, not a problem for existing clients. Thanks!