# Sharing common protocol buffer message definitions

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Is it possible to share message definitions across multiple protocol buffer files?

Specifically I want to share the definition so that the rcp declaration can use it. For example:

```
package common;

message EmptyMessage{
}
```

```
import "common/common.proto";

service MyService {
  rpc MyEndPoint (common.EmptyMessage) returns (common.EmptyMessage);
}
```

But protoc does not like that format. It seems like maybe I could alias the request/response messages, but I'm trying to reduce the amount of boilerplate, not just redirect it.

Is there anyway to use common message definitions in this way?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for Go when you define a `go_package` option. Assuming you have this file structure:

```
test
testapi
├── common
│   └── common.proto
└── entry.proto
```

with `common.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package common;
option go_package = "testapi/common";

message EmptyMessage{}
```

and `entry.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package entry;
import "common/common.proto";
option go_package = "testapi/entry";

service MyService {
  rpc MyEndPoint (common.EmptyMessage) returns (common.EmptyMessage);
}
```

Then you can start this script from the base folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

OUT_DIR="./test"

protoc --proto_path="./testapi" \
    --go_out=${OUT_DIR} \
    --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=${OUT_DIR} \
    --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    entry.proto \
    common/common.proto
```

and find all the generated files in `test/`.

Several IDEs might offer additional support. For example with a JetBrains IDE you can add `testapi` to the `Import Paths` like this
[image: Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Protocol Buffers]
(red color is for hightlighting *coughcough*)

Of course, for the generated files to work (and import properly), you need a configured `go.mod` in a parent folder.

Edit: As hinted by DazWilkin, for empty message you can even rely on the vendored `Empty` type, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504658/5767484) example. GRPC comes with a couple of predefined general purpose `messages`. To make them available (resp. found by the `protoc` compiler), ensure that the bundled `include/` folder resides next to the `bin` folder that contains the `protoc` executable when you install the protobuf compiler following [these](https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/#install-pre-compiled-binaries-any-os) instructions.

Comment: This answer is good. There's an expanded answer too which is exemplified by Google's [Well-Known Types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) which include an [`Empty`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#empty) type. In this approach, like with 3rd-party Protos, the common protos would be in a **different** Go module. Following this pattern more closely reflects intent, reduces code duplication, decouples changes etc.

Comment: @DazWilkin Sure you can also do stuff as `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";`, which will be found by default if they reside in an `include` folder next to `protoc's` `bin` folder. Just not sure how longer my answer should become, that's why I dropped that.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. The Well-Known-Types is good to know too. If I switched to google.protobuf.Empty type would that mean the client for this protobuf would now need to import both my service protobuf as well as the google.protobuf.Empty in order to make those requests? So it appears I can either reduce imports, but duplicate definitions in protobufs or I can reduce imports but duplicate a lot of definitions in protobufs.

Comment: @user22335954 Your client as well as you service should use `import "google/protobuf/empty.proto"` and you can/should drop your custom `EmptyMessage` definition at all places. Not sure I'm getting your question, though.